# Indentation error with print function

Tags: python

Normally I do all my programming in Java, but I have a bit of python code I'm converting to java.

What I'm not getting is the indentation style, which is cool because that's the way things are done in python, what I need to do though is just add a 
couple of `print()` functions to the code just to make sure that I'm getting the correct result.

For example

```
def relImgCoords2ImgPlaneCoords(self, pt, imageWidth, imageHeight):        
    ratio = imageWidth / float(imageHeight)
    sw = ratio
    sh = 1
    return [sw * (pt[0] - 0.5), sh * (pt[1] - 0.5)]
```

It doesn't seem to matter how the `print` function is indented it shows an indent error, what's the trick?

or

```
    else:
        if scn.optical_center_type == 'camdata':
            #get the principal point location from camera data
            P = [x for x in  activeSpace.clip.tracking.camera.principal]
            #print("camera data optical center", P[:])
            P[0] /= imageWidth
            P[1] /= imageHeight
            #print("normlz. optical center", P[:])
            P = self.relImgCoords2ImgPlaneCoords(P, imageWidth, imageHeight)
        elif scn.optical_center_type == 'compute':
            if len(vpLineSets) < 3:
                self.report({'ERROR'}, "A third grease pencil layer is needed to compute the optical center.")
                return{'CANCELLED'}
            #compute the principal point using a vanishing point from a third gp layer.
            #this computation does not rely on the order of the line sets
            vps = [self.computeIntersectionPointForLineSegments(vpLineSets[i]) for i in range(len(vpLineSets))]
            vps = [self.relImgCoords2ImgPlaneCoords(vps[i], imageWidth, imageHeight) for i in range(len(vps))]
            P = self.computeTriangleOrthocenter(vps)
        else:
            #assume optical center in image midpoint
            pass
```

I want to see what the return values of the `vps` variables are in `elif` part of the code block, where do I put the `print` function call?

Comment: show the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not seem to be any issues with where you are placing the commented out `print` statements.

The most likely case is that you are mixing indents with spaces causing indention errors.

Try using the `reindent.py` script in the `Tools/scripts` directory of where you installed Python.

Comment: I use eclipse for my java development so have installed pydev, how do I run reindent.py?

Comment: After locating the reindent.py file, you use the command line to run "python reindent.py bad_file.py" where "bad_file.py" is the file that has the IndentionError. This causes the new file to use 4-space indents.

Comment: Also, if you are having trouble finding reindent.py or it isn't included with your Python distribution, you can also "pip install reindent".